# Mongoose - `CastError: Cast to number failed` when using "$fieldName"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose schema:

```
{
    lastEdit: Number
    translations: [{
      submittedTimestamp: Number
      ...
    }]
    ...
}
```

And the following query:

```
Model.findOne({
    "translations.submittedTimestamp": { $lte: "$lastEdit" }
})
```

However, I get an error saying `CastError: Cast to number failed for value "$lastEdit" at path "submittedTimestamp" for model "translations"`.

If I plug in a static number instead of `$lastEdit`, in this case a Unix timestamp, the query works fine, which means that it has to do with the way I've used `"$lastEdit"`. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
Model.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      { "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$translations",
          "cond": { "$lte": ["$$this.submittedTimestamp", "$lastEdit"] }
        }
      }},
      1
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Yup, you're right, I had just realized that and as I was changing my code to make sure, you posted an answer. Hopefully this can benefit someone in the future! I'll accept the answer once the 5 min are up

Comment: I know this is a little late, but the following doesn't seem to be working either: `$expr: { $lte: ["$translations.submittedTimestamp", "$lastEdit"] }`. However, again, if I replace `"$translations.submittedTimestamp"` with a static value, it does work.

Comment: If I switch the values in the array, then it just always returns as true... Plus the MongoDB docs say that the first value should be the one thats less than or equal to, which in my case should be `translations.submittedTimestamp`

Comment: Got it I just saw that your `translations.submittedTimestamp` is an array field. So to with which element do you want to match the `lastEdit` ?

Comment: `translations` is an array of objects, and `translations.submittedTimestamp` is a Number. I need to find the docs that have any `submittedTimestamp` that's less than or equal to `lastEdit`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Here is the sample https://mongoplayground.net/p/SrnnjZtWihY

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm late, but this seems to be working. Time to read through docs on what all this does haha. Thanks!